# LG Ultrafine 5K volume too loud

Tags: keyboard, display, audio, sound-volume

I have the LG Ultrafine 5K screen, and the volume is extremely loud if I move the slider to more than 20%. The screenshot below shows a rather normal listening volume. If I double it, it's very loud, but it's still at only 20% or less.

Anything over that, it sounds like the speakers are broken.

Is anyone else having this issue? The problem it causes is that I don't have fine control over the volume, for example when using the volume keys up or down, it moves in too big steps.

Is there a way to "rescale" the volume slider, or cap it at a maximum value somehow, so I can use the entire slider without becoming deaf?

[image]

Comment: What app is making the sound? Check with well programmed apps like QuickTime player and iTunes and also check system volume as opposed to app or web player volume.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. I have filed a bug report with apple. In my case when changing brightness on the LG display MacOS becomes incredibly slow.

Answer (score 13):

This is fixed in the latest firmware from LG. Unfortunately you have to install it via their Screen Manager software, available [here](http://www.lg.com/us/support-product/lg-27MD5KA-B#manuals), but it seems to resolve the issue for the most part.

Comment: **This is the answer**. I had this issue for about year, and used the various workarounds mentioned here, but installing the new monitor firmware resolves the issue so things work normally.

Comment: FYI - the linked page just tells you to download the LG Screen Manager app from the Mac App Store, so you can save yourself a click.

Answer (score 9):

You can make fine adjustments to your volume level by holding <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> while you press <kbd>F11</kbd> <kbd>F12</kbd> (Volume Up/Down).  this way, it won't make those big jumps.

As for the cause of the volume issue - it appears you aren't alone as evidenced by this [Apple discussion thread](https://origin-discussions-us.apple.com/thread/7816424?start=0&tstart=0) and this [thread](http://www.imore.com/lg-5k).  Everything that I have read says they are waiting on a software update

Answer (score 3):

Desr Sir,
I recently purchased the newest model of the Apple MacBook Air and the LG Ultrafine 4K. I had the same issue that the speakers went into overdrive as soon as I turned up the volume to more that 20%. I installed the latest version of the LG screen manager. After a few restarts it resolved this issue.

Comment: This did work for me. It's much more reasonable now. I did note that after the first restart it didn't work. After the second restart, the volume is much more reasonable. Such a relief!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to have the following settings on my LG 5K (and 4K) display.

System preferences:

- alert sound 25%
- system volume 75%

Then I use iTunes to control the volume based on the music (sometimes I use SoundCheck automatic volume adjustment - sometimes I don't).

[image]

The speakers are louder than I need them to be, but I can get very soft background music without much fuss using the controls above. I ordered both for testing as soon as they were released and didn't need any software updates for either. I do run macOS 10.12.4 today but didn't have issues on older OS when the displays initially arrived a few months back.

Comment: Interesting, so what happens if you play a video in safari like on youtube with the volume on max in youtubes controls?

Comment: I don't run max volume on iTunes so max volume in safari would also be loud. Wouldn't max volume be in loud be correct behavior, @Niclas