# LG UltraFine 5K firmware update

Tags: display, 5k

I have an LG Ultrafine 5K (27MD5KA-B) monitor. I finally wanted to fix the [volume issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278044/lg-ultrafine-5k-volume-too-loud) and just found out that there should be a firmware update that is supposed to be installed through the LG Screen Manager software.

I've installed LG Screen Manager and it says that my monitor is up to date with version 3.01.,1.11, 5234,3.00

From what I've gathered, there should be at least version 3.04,1.13,5237,3.04,0.1e

I've also tried to find a firmware file to manually download, but all links I could find are dead, e.g.:

http://lmu.lge.com/ExternalService/lgscreenmanager/mac/FW/27MD5KA_MP3/MODEL_27MD5KA_SV3.04_CV1.13_HV5237_NV3.04_AV0.1e_20170705.zip

http://lmu.lge.com/ExternalService/lgscreenmanager/mac/FW/27MD5KA_MP3/FWLatestVersion.txt

The monitor is from January 2017, so it is one of the earliest models that also suffered from the shielding issues (which has been fixed). It's attached to a 2016 MacBook Pro 15" Touchbar, still running MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6

I would appreciate any hints on how to update the firmware or links to the firmware file.

**Update:** I've just poked around LG Screen Manager with Charles Proxy and realized that it tries to fetch `FWLatestVersion.txt` link above.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about Apple hardware, software, or services as defined in the [Help Center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: @Allan from my understanding of the [relevant page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), this question is on-topic: "If you have a question about a practical problem you are trying to solve as a user of... third-party hardware, services and software when associated for use with Apple products." This monitor is marketed as MacOS-only.

Comment: It's still and LG product and issue even if it is "Mac only."  You're having firmware issues including where to download and LG  is the only one who can adequately address.  Did you contact their support?

Comment: Yes, I have contacted LG support, but haven't heard back yet. After my last interaction with them, I wouldn't be surprised if this community turned out to be more competent and helpful than the official support.

Comment: I am running into the same issue with the 22MD4KA-B model. I'm guessing that it's due to the same issues you're having. There is a short thread going on lg's forum that is related: https://lgcommunity.us.com/discussion/comment/6471/#Comment_6471. Really hoping to be able to update to resolve some issues I've been having with waking from sleep. Sometimes my MacBook just straight up turns off if I leave it connected for a while.

Comment: so far I've exchanged many emails and a few phone calls with LG who insist there's no updates available on their end. This is super frustrating as it's well documented that 3.11 exists for the 22MD4KA-B model. I've asked repeatedly for a link to the update file so if I receive this I'll be sure to pass it on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After about four weeks I got a reply from LG support with a firmware file attached.

Here is some information about the file:

- Filename:
  MODEL_27MD5KA_SV3.04_CV1.13_HV5237_NV3.04_AV0.1e_20170705.zip
- Filesize: 304347 bytes
- MD5: b03322ad668849ee5112ce24159c5c93

It's an encrypted ZIP file that can be opened with LG Screen Manager. With that file, I've successfully updated my monitor to version (3.04,1.13, 5237,3.04,0.1e).

Comment: I was able to update through LG Screen Manager and can confirm that the latest version is what you are now on (31-May-19)

Comment: Appreciate you posting this. I found the same info elsewhere and was trepidatious to download the zip file from an unknown source. But your experience validates that this is really someone trying to help in SPITE of LG's poor support. I'm off to try updating my firmware!

Comment: it's 2022, can confirm that LG Screen Manager still showing 3.04 is the latest. Aside, it took jumping through a lot of hurdles to find the LG Screen Manager. LG Chat support told me it didn't exist.